# Discontinuous bounded holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there any bounded holomorphic function on the unit disk whose limit (not just radial) exists at all boundary points expect one point?

Comment: What about $e^{\frac{1+z}{z-1}}$?

Comment: Thanks! I thought continuity on the boundary (except one point) would somehow release us from the hard-checking condition of Piravalov theorem.